# Deleting duplicate entry in SQL

Tags: sql

Would you please help me to solve this duplication entry issue?

I have columns in my table as shown below;

```
**Date_time**           **Pro**                **Color**
2016-10-17              Basketball               Red
2016-10-17              Basketball               Red
2016-10-18              Hockey                   Silver
2016-10-18              Hockey                   Silver
```

I need to delete duplicated entries and ending up having;

```
**Date_time**           **Pro**                **Color**
2016-10-17      Basketball               Red
2016-10-18      Hockey                   Silver
```

I used this code to get what I want however, I was not success on my attempting.

```
DELETE FROM Sport WHERE date_time NOT IN (SELECT MIN(date_time)
    FROM sport GROUP BY date_time,pro,color)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, explain what "not success" means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
DELETE FROM Sport
    WHERE s.date_time > (SELECT MIN(s2.date_time)
                         FROM sport s2
                         WHERE s2.pro = sport.pro and s2.color = sport.color
                        );
```

In fact, if you have multiple duplicated entries, then the above only removes one of them.  Try something like this instead:

```
DELETE FROM Sport
    WHERE s.date_time = (SELECT MAX(s2.date_time)
                         FROM sport s2
                         WHERE s2.pro = sport.pro and s2.color = sport.color
                        );
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 's'.

Comment: Most databases accept that syntax.  You really should tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH numbered AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [dupe-column-list] ORDER BY [dupe-column-list]) AS _dupe_num 
    FROM [table-name] 
    WHERE 1=1 -- any where clause if required
)
DELETE FROM numbered WHERE _dupe_num > 1;
```

The above query will use `ROW_NUMBER()` to only keep the first appearance of each record. In your case the `[dupe-column-list]` should include all your columns.